# mysqli_query - return values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using the PHP function `mysqli_query` to run a `SELECT` query.

What does `mysqli_query` return if the query runs successfully, but the query finds no matches?

Comment: I had read the manual page and still wasn't sure of the answer for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

A query that runs but returns no results is still considered a "successful query", since the query did run in the database and an empty result set is a legitimate response. This means the query will still return a `mysqli_result` object, and if you check its row count (either via `$result->num_rows` in the object-oriented style or `mysqli_num_rows($result)` in the procedural style) it will return 0.

Comment: Version 5.6 returns true on windows, if is null. So this isn't a general case. ` if($result=$this->_mysql->query("SELECT SQL_CACHE x1,x2 FROM test_table;")){ /*it enters here cause it's true but it should not*/   while($res=$result->fetch_assoc()) { /*bla bla bla*/}}`

Answer (score 4):

A `Mysqli_query` object, than you can use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to count the number of rows returned. So:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data"))
{
    $count = $result->num_rows; 
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $count);
    $result->close();
}
```

From [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.