# Unable To Execute SQL Query In PHP & Return A Value

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

```
$username = $_POST["txtUsername"];  
$query = "SELECT Password FROM `tblusers` WHERE Username='admin'";
mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

I don't entirely know how to return the result of this query, any help is appreciated but bare in mind I am fairly new so I may struggle to understand.

Comment: The information you need is in the PHP manual. You should be studying that if you have no idea what you're doing. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're new, I'd encourage using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects).  The main reason is to protect your website from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
function getPassword() {
    try {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=192.168.0.1;charset=utf8", "username", "password");
        $username = $_POST["txtUsername"];
        $cmd = $db->prepare("
            SELECT Password FROM `tblusers` WHERE Username = :username;
        ");
        $cmd->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $cmd->execute();
        $result = $cmd->fetch();
        return $result[0];
    } catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); return; }
}

$password = getPassword();
```

Comment: I changed all the bits and bobs I needed to but I still don't get anything. I tried the SQL in my database and it finds what I want it to so I know my SQL isn't incorrect.

Comment: I'm assuming you've double checked the host, username and password for connecting to the database?

Comment: I think so - it looks like this: "mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8", "root", "root".

Where do I add the database name?

Comment: The database name isn't necessary, but you can add it to the first string like this: "mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=mydb"

Comment: It works now - thank you very much. I've been trying to do this for 2 days now.

Comment: Great - adding the dbname fixed it?  Mind marking my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Basic example

```
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    $DB_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';
    $DB_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST';
    $DB_USER = 'DATABASE_USER';
    $DB_PASS = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

// A QUICK QUERY ON A FAKE USER TABLE
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status`='bonkers'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

// GOING THROUGH THE DATA
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo stripslashes($row['username']);    
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }

// CLOSE CONNECTION
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp

`mysqli_query` returns a result set, use `myqli_fetch_array` to get the actual query results.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli_query` return `mysqli_result` object for successful `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN` queries, So you have to create a variable to hold the object.

**Note**: it will return `FALSE` on failure

*Read more* : [mysqli_query - return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419593/mysqli-query-return-values)